# Spatial Indexing for Nearby Way SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, spatial-index

In my SQL Server database, I have a table `Way` with columns `WayId` (uniqueId) and `LineObject` (Created with expression  `Geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(long1 lat1, long2 lat12')`)

I have to find out the nearby Way for one location of type geography,  Created like 'POINT(Long Lat)'.

Is it possible to get performance improvement with spatial index? If so, please guide to achieve the same.

```
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(long lat)'

Select top 1 *
From Way
Order by LineObject.STDistance(@g)
```

Expected is performance improvement.

Comment: SQL performance related question require the execution plan, ideally using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: Without even seeing a query plan I would expect that to be a very slow query. It's effectively going to do a table scan so that it can perform sqrt-based calculations to calculate the distance for every row in your table.

Comment: Spatial indexes for geography types, if you have any, support [limited predicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview#geography). You may experience better performance if you pre-filter the rowset down to a manageable level by using the `geography1.STDistance(geography2) <= number` form before trying to apply a sort over the distance calculation.

Comment: The nearest neighbor type of query also supports spatial indexes however only if a specific query syntax is written. The appropriate syntax is:
`SELECT TOP(K) [WITH TIES] *   
FROM <Table> AS T [WITH(INDEX(<SpatialIndex>))]  
WHERE <SpatialColumn>.STDistance(@reference_object) IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY <SpatialColumn>.STDistance(@reference_object) [;] `

Comment: A spatial index could improve performance: `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX spidxLineObject ON Way(LineObject)
USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID WITH (GRIDS = (LOW, LOW, HIGH, HIGH), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 64);

declare @g geography;
Select top (1) with ties *
From Way with(index(spidxLineObject))
where LineObject.STDistance(@g) is not null 
Order by LineObject.STDistance(@g)`

Comment: "Is it possible to get performance improvement with spatial index?" - yes, it's possible. As @lptr suggests, spatial indexes support "k-nearest neighbor" queries (as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor). *Will* a spatial index improve your query? [Run your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)